# Reason for Java IDE generating methods with void return type when extract method shortcut is used

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I was recently reading a java class where the person had created methods via IDE shortcut( extract method shortcut ). All methods had a return type of void and what was supposed to be return type was passed as input parameter for the method. Below is an example of what i'm referring to.

```
public void multiply(Integer first, Integer second, Integer result){
   result = first * second;
}
```

I was wondering if the above is a good way of doing things. I personally do not like the above way of creating methods. I think the method should have been like below.

```
public Integer multiply(Integer first, Integer second, Integer result){
   return first * second;
}
```

But in IntelliJ/Eclipse when we do extract method mostly creates method like above.

Can someone please let me know why IDE's usually create void method when we use the extract method shortcut and is the 1st style of method definition a good practice at all?

Comment: Can you ahow the code before extraction?

Answer (score 0):

If the method being called isn't being assigned to a variable, Eclipse has no way to know what the return value is supposed to be.

Presumably, the original code looked something like this:

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
   Integer result = 0;
   multiply(1,3,result);
 }
```

There's no way for Eclipse to divine that `multiply` is supposed to return anything, so it defaults to `void`. If you want to infer return values, have it be assigned to a variable like so:

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
   Integer result = 0;
   result = multiply(1,3,result);
 }
```